# Docusign Send on Behalf Of (SOBO)

Tags: docusignapi

If any one has it, I'd welcome an example of how to use Docusign's Send on Behalf Of (SOBO) functionality.

I'm using the SOAP API with XML, and even Docusign's Level III support has not been able to come up with a sample.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### April 2021 Update

Neither SOBO nor Legacy Authentication is supported for new REST API integrations. Instead, use an OAuth v2.0 authentication grant. The replacement for the SOBO pattern is to use the JWT grant which enables the application to impersonate any DocuSign user who has given consent to the application to do so. Open a new q here on StackOverflow if you have questions.

### Original answer

For clarification purposes, SOBO simply allows a System Sender to authenticate and make API calls on behalf of a user sending envelopes. If you're looking for specific sample codes for this it can be found in the [Send on Behalf Of Information Guide.](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/send-on-behalf-of-functionality-guide.pdf)

However, our DocuSign for Salesforce manage package utilizes SOBO and I took a header sample from an envelope I sent. In this case I am the System Sender as well as the actual sender of the envelope. If utilizing SOBO in the "real world" the  GUID would contain the username of the sender.

```
X-DocuSign-Authentication: 
<DocuSignCredentials>
    <Username>c483bf85-c71b-4d5f-b0bf-cfacb390bbf7</Username>
    <Password>[omitted]</Password>
    <IntegratorKey>[omitted]</IntegratorKey>
    <SendOnBehalfOf>c483bf85-c71b-4d5f-b0bf-cfacb390bbf7</SendOnBehalfOf>
</DocuSignCredentials>
```

For example, if you were a member of my account and your username was placed in that string then the envelope would send from you and be in your Sent Items folder while I as the system sender authenticate and make all the API calls for you.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Yup, that did it, thanks very much. 

Docusign's support staff had led me down all sorts of wrong roads and lots of "we don't know if you can do that."

This works as well:

<SendOnBehalfOf>[Email Address]</SendOnBehalfOf>

where [Email Address] is the sobo's email address.