# Docusign api - Sending envelope on behalf of another user

Tags: php, docusignapi

I have the admin account on docusign which I connect the api client with its credentials.

```
$client = new Client([
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'integrator_key' => $integrator_key,
    'host' => $host
]);
```

I have multiple users on this account and I can fetch the list of users (as well as their ids).

```
$client->users->callList()
```

I am trying to send an envelope on behalf of a user beside the admin account (so it doesn't show admin's name in the email, instead it shows that users details), however I am confused how to do that.

How do I do that using Docusign PHP Client? Or is it not possible with PHP Client so that I should use curl instead [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19780273/4705339)?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with the PHP client, because this is a legacy feature that requires you to use the legacy authentication.

If you want to know how to do it using the legacy authentication, here is another thread showing how to do that  - [Docusign Send on Behalf Of (SOBO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617735/docusign-send-on-behalf-of-sobo)